# Problem with rep requirement for comment ability

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments

We have a user Ronnie who asked [a decent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467771/function-calculate-area-of-region-under-parabola) yesterday without registering a proper account (or something - I'm not overly familiar with the account system here). He came back today and was unable to login, and therefore unable to comment on his question. So he went off and created [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475505/area-under-a-parabola-closed) [identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475799/help-solve-an-answer-closed) questions to contunie the discussions. Quite understandable of a new user, but those with the rep (me included) rushed to close the dupes.

Is there anything that can be done to improve this situation? IMHO, it's a case of the rep requirement for commenting doing harm.